# Backbone Router and Prerenderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I have a backbone application which uses hashes. With the application you can create pages with dynamic content. I want those pages indexed in Google so when people create pages, they can be found in google.

The best option I found was to use [prerender](https://prerender.io/) and I have followed the instructions regarding backbone.

I have installed the prerender library with npm

```
 $ npm install prerender-node --save
```

Added the require module in express

```
 app.use(require('prerender-node'));
```

Then I switched my the "#" to "#!"

"If your url uses #, make sure to change it to #! " according to the website.

So, in the router of my application I changed the hashes to hasbangs.

```
 var Myrouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({ 
     routes: {
       "!login": "login",
       "!create": "create",
       "!page:id": "page", 
       "!edit": "edit", 
     }
...more code
});
```

Then I test a page with the url for example:

I enter the url `http://localhost:8080/#!page/532e499b4e3c090200000004`

And according to prerender, the hasbang should change  ?_escaped_fragment_=

So it should look like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_= page/532e499b4e3c090200000004
```

Nothing happens! What am I doing wrong!! It just displays the webpage, and the hashbang is not changing!!

Note: Is this the correct way of doing it? Because in some examples I see the urls are of the form  http://mywebsite.com/#!/page/ and if it is this way how do I have to change my backbone routing. I already tried changing the routing also to:

```
 var Myrouter = Backbone.Router.extend ({ 
     routes: {
       "!/login": "login",
       "!/create": "create",
       "!/page:id": "page", 
       "!/edit": "edit", 
     }
...more code
});
```

So the url would be like this `http://localhost:8080/#!/page/532e499b4e3c090200000004`

But not luck!

Please somebody guide me to the right way!!

Answer (score 1):

You should start both https://github.com/prerender/prerender and your node project with backbone in public folder at the SAME TIME BOTH.

First clone the prerender, run npm install and start it. In the process I've got an error with gyp. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'script_main'. Just remove the gyp you already got with: sudo apt-get remove gyp and It will install a new one

NOTE: To work both at the same time they have to be on a different port lik 3000 and 3001 for example

After this my prerender.io works as expected

Comment: Goce is correct. If you're running on localhost, you have to run the Prerender server locally because the hosted Prerender.io service cannot access your localhost. You are correct that http://localhost:8080/#!page/532e499b4e3c090200000004 should become http://localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_=page/532e499b4e3c090200000004

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's documentation there should not be slash after `#!`. You can read more at: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: This does not work! I all ready read this page before and this page doesn't consider backbone case where I use routing with hashes. Or at least explain how to do it please! I already took out the slash after #! and didn't work either.

Comment: Does `prerender` make request to your express app when you make request like: `http://localhost:8080/?_escaped_fragment_=page/532e499b4e3c090200000004` ?

Comment: No, apparently, you have your normal url, and prerender should change your url to the escaped fragment, according to the prerender [link] (https://prerender.io/).